# Background black or colors after closing lid

Tags: laptop, desktop-background, lid

Every time I install ubuntu on a laptop and close the lid (I think it goes to sleep then). 
If I open the lid again the background image is black or very weird like this:

[image]

I am using ubuntu 19.04. I don't know if this is relevant but this is my gpu: GeForce 940MX/PCIe/SSE2

Does someone know how I can fix this. My laptop is completely usable and I feel stupid for asking this. But if someone knows how to fix this please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed with the new version of ubuntu (19.10).

I don't really now if this is why it is fixed but I suspect it, never had this problem again.

Thanks anyway!